# Find last td without using Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, css, no-framework

I need to find the Last td of every row in a HTML table, and remove a css from that td. Can I do it without using Jquery.
How?

Comment: will javascript work for you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use css3 `last-child` property for this. Write like this:

```
tr td:last-child{
 color:red;
}
```

But it's not work in IE8 & below.

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS

```
td:last-child: {
  //your style here
}
```

[Docs on CSS3 selectors here](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors)

or using traverse the DOM using JavaScript :

```
var mytable = document.getElementById('tableid');
var myrows = mytable.getElementsByTagName("tr");
var lastrow = myrows[myrows.length -1];
var mycells = lastrow.getElementsByTagName("td");
var lastcell = mycells[mycells.length -1];
// set CSS property here
lastcell.style.color = "red";
```

`lastcell` is your last `td`

[Working example using JavaScript](http://jsfiddle.net/zpDNU/)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using CSS3 selectors? E.g

```
tr td:last-child
  {
    YOUR CODE HERE
  }
```

You could also look at using classes to show which td's are the last. But of course this isnt dynamic.

I believe there is also a normal javascript answer but im not very good at that :P

http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/firstchild.html

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are not looking for css type solution

```
rows=document.getElementsByTagName('tr')
for (var i=0; i<rows.length; i++){
    columns=rows[i].getElementsByTagName('td');
    mytd = columns[columns.length-1];
    classname = mytd.className;
    arr = classname.split(' ');
    mytd.className = arr.filter(function(e){return e!=CLASSTOREMOVE}).join(' ');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For a pure JavaScript solution:

```
function removeCssClass(tableId, cssClass) {
    var trs = null;
    var tr = null;
    var tds = null;
    var td = null;
    var classes = [];
    var i = 0;

    trs = document.getElementById(tableId).getElementsByTagName('tr');
    tds = trs[trs.length - 1].getElementsByTagName('td');
    td = tds[tds.length - 1];
    classes = td.className.split(' ');
    for (i = 0; i < classes.length; i += 1) {
        if (classes[i] === cssClass) {
            classes.pop(i);
        }
    }
    td.className = classes.join(' ');
    return false;
}​
```

Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/urcu4/).

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do with the last TD? If you are wanting to have a border in-between each td why don't you use border-left and then you can use first-child to remove it. There might be a better approach that is more compatible with browsers.