# Insert a new Row of Input fields when the Bottom Row gets Focus using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am building a ToDO style list.  My goal is to insert a new Row every time the last/bottom row's Name Text Input field gets focus.

So clicking in the bottom input field would insert a new row below it,  which I could then finish typing my name and hit tab to proceed to the next, which would then again add a new row below it as well.

[image]

My name input fileds look like this...

```
<input class="name" name="name_1" id="name_1" size=45 type="text" value="" onfocus="myFunction(event)">
```

As you can see, right now, when the text input gets Focus `onfocus="myFunction(event)"` it calls this text function `myFunction(event)`

```
function myFunction(e){
  add_task_row("","{$ID}","","","","","","","0");
  return false;
}
```

My `add_task_row` handles inserting the new rows.

It currently works, anytime I click or tab into a text input, it adds a new row.  THe problme is it happens on any row, I need it to only function this way when that very last row is focused on.

I think inside the `myFunction()` it could possibly have some code that would count the number of rows and then only `fire the add_task_row` if it is the current last row?  I just don't know enough JavaScript to do this myself or even know if I'm on the right track to do this?

Any help appreciated, you can see my desired output/result.  Would like to use as much native JavaScript as possible

Comment: Think about coding "onfocus" only on the last row in the original HTML.  Then, each time you add a row, you could call a `removeFocus(this)` routine so that only the newly-added last row would have the `onfocus` attribute.

Comment: Are you using jQuery?  it's easy to use the last selector to see what row you are on:  `$('#yourtableid tr:last')`   if not, you'll need to do some iterating ala http://stackoverflow.com/a/9718646/1981678

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so this should work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#table1').on('click','tr:last',function(){
        alert("!");
        $('#table1 tbody:last').append("\n<tr><td>Test</td></tr>");
    });
});
```

And the table to the Script:

```
<table id="table1">
<tr><td>Test1</td></tr>
<tr><td>Test2</td></tr>
</table>
```

So on clicking "Test2" a new row will be generated with content "Test".

(I hope you're using jQuery because this is much simplier. If not here: http://jquery.com/ Try it out.)

Greetings

Comment: I prefer native JS as the whole entire ap;plication is without jQuery so far.  Also my rows are much more complext code and are DIVs instead of tables, the existinbg content cant be changed

Answer (score 0):

It turns out to be easy using only native JavaScript; code the `onfocus` attribute on the last row only of your initial HTML and do this:

`<input type="text" onfocus="alert('focus');this.removeAttribute('onfocus');" >`

Replace the alert with your function to build a new row (with an `onfocus` attribute.)  At any  given instant, only the last row, whether original or inserted, will have an `onfocus` attribute.

Edit: Or maybe call `this.removeAttribute` *before* the call to build a new row; that way, there will be a period of a few microseconds where no input element has an `on focus` rather than a period of time where two rows have such an attribute.  It's a small thing, but I am a worrier.